# Fixed background images not displaying correctly on any web browser

Tags: css, images

Screenshot for this question:

[image: Background image not displaying correctly]

I am using fixed position images as seen at 
css-tricks.com/examples/BlurryBackgroundEffect/ 
to create a glassy effect to a web project I'm working on. As you can see on the screenshot above often the content block image fails to display until the browser is forced to make a redraw by scrolling etc.

I've tried preloading them, using both onload and hidden `img` tags separately, but it still happens.

This is not a massive issue but if anyone understands why this occurs it would be really helpful.

Comment: Could you post a link or some code?  It's going to be near impossible to help given that we can't actually see where the problem is coming from.

Comment: sorry the site is local currently. Will once it goes live I guess. Dont worry about it and thanks for having a look.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to trigger a redraw you could always use:

```
body { display: none }
```

then

```
window.onload = function () {
    document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].display = 'block';
}
```

this will make the page load seem much longer.

The best advice I've read on controlling the load/redraw across browsers has been [Steve Souders Even Faster Web Sites](http://www.stevesouders.com/blog/2009/04/23/even-faster-web-sites/).

**Note:**

Remember you can always put the relevant sections on a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) so that others can help (images can be uploaded to [ImageShack](http://imageshack.us/) and included by using the provided "Direct Link").